# FluentValidation RuleForEach not detecting error?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, fluentvalidation

i have a rule defined below where the PreferredAirlineCodes is a string[] type

```
RuleForEach(x => x.PreferredAirlineCodes).Length(2);
```

however when I ran the following test...

```
validator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.PreferredAirlineCodes, new []{"CX", "3KK"});
```

the test failed... did i defined the rule wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule is defined fine.

However the `ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor` is only meant for testing simple cases: to test simple property validation rules. So it is not supporting testing nested properties or arrays (see also this [issue](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/workitem/7095))

So you need to test this validation rule "manually":

```
var validator = new MyClassValidator();
var result = validator.Validate(
    new MyClass() { PreferredAirlineCodes = new[] {"CX", "3KK"}});
Assert.IsTrue( 
    result.Errors.Any(e => e.PropertyName.StartsWith("PreferredAirlineCodes")));
```

Comment: Thanks... hopefully the next version will have the ability to simple test collection types